# Flexbox headings get pushed up when in tablet/mobile view

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid, responsive

I have a simple layout where I used grid and flexbox inside grid to position icons and text (headings and paragaphs) next to each other.

[Normal heading alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXa5Q.jpg)

However, when I minimize the viewport to see the layout in responsive view (tablet or mobile), these headings get pushed up and they don't align with each other anymore.

I was wondering if there is a way to make headings always align next to each other without being pushed up when in tablet view. Also it would be great if it was achievable without Javascript as I'm learning html & css.

Also a bonus question - is there a possibility for the icons on my website to scale down as well (the get smaller as the window gets smaller).

Thank you from a newbie

[Headings not aligned with each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brgdD.jpg)

```css
/*Services*/

.main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: 300px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 7rem 10rem 5rem 10rem;
    row-gap: 5rem;
      
}

.headingservice {
    font-family: "GTAmericaRegular";
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.paragraphservice {
    font-family: "GTAmericaRegular";
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
  
}


.text a {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: #4C5FD5;
    text-decoration: none;
}



/*Icons*/

.image img {
    width: 50px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 0 30px 30px 30px;
}

.services {
    display: flex;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;

}
```

```html
<section class="main">
    
    <div class="services">
        <div class="image"><img src="/images/repair-equipment.png"></div>
        <div class="text">
            <h1 class="headingservice">Using Abstract</h1>
            <p class="paragraphservice">Abstract lets you manage, version, and document your designs in one place.</p>
            <a href="#">Learn more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="services">
        <div class="image"><img src="/images/cashmachine.png"></div>
        <div class="text">
            <h1 class="headingservice">Manage your account</h1>
            <p class="paragraphservice">Configure your account settings, such as your email, profile details, and password.</p>
            <a href="#">Learn more</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="services">
        <div class="image"><img src="/images/sketchbook.png"></div>
        <div class="text">
            <h1 class="headingservice">Manage organizations, teams and projects</h1>
            <p class="paragraphservice">Use Abstract organizations, teams, and projects to organize your people and your work.</p>
            <a href="#">Learn more</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="services">
        <div class="image"><img src="/images/braille.png"></div>
        <div class="text">
            <h1 class="headingservice">Manage billing</h1>
            <p class="paragraphservice">Change subscriptions and payment details.</p>
            <a href="#">Learn more</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="services">
        <div class="image"><img src="/images/graduation.png"></div>
        <div class="text">
            <h1 class="headingservice">Authenticate to Abstract</h1>
            <p class="paragraphservice">Set up and configure SSO, SCIM, and Just-in-Time provisioning.</p>
            <a href="#">Learn more</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="services">
        <div class="image"><img src="/images/open.png"></div>
        <div class="text">
            <h1 class="headingservice">Abstract support</h1>
            <p class="paragraphservice">Get in touch with a human</p>
            <a href="#">Learn more</a>
        </div>
    </div>

 </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the headlines rise up is logical, because. you have the vertical center alignment set, and the blocks have different heights. Try it like this, but it would be nice to see how it should be in order to give more competent advice.

```css
/*Services*/

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 300px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 7rem 10rem 5rem 10rem;
  row-gap: 5rem;
}

.headingservice {
  font-family: "GTAmericaRegular";
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.paragraphservice {
  font-family: "GTAmericaRegular";
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.text a {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #4C5FD5;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*Icons*/

.image img {
  width: 50px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0 30px 30px 30px;
}

.services {
  display: flex;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main,
.services {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.image img {
  margin: 30px 30px 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">

  <div class="services">
    <div class="image"><img src="/images/repair-equipment.png"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <h1 class="headingservice">Using Abstract</h1>
      <p class="paragraphservice">Abstract lets you manage, version, and document your designs in one place.</p>
      <a href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="services">
    <div class="image"><img src="/images/cashmachine.png"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <h1 class="headingservice">Manage your account</h1>
      <p class="paragraphservice">Configure your account settings, such as your email, profile details, and password.</p>
      <a href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="services">
    <div class="image"><img src="/images/sketchbook.png"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <h1 class="headingservice">Manage organizations, teams and projects</h1>
      <p class="paragraphservice">Use Abstract organizations, teams, and projects to organize your people and your work.</p>
      <a href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="services">
    <div class="image"><img src="/images/braille.png"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <h1 class="headingservice">Manage billing</h1>
      <p class="paragraphservice">Change subscriptions and payment details.</p>
      <a href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="services">
    <div class="image"><img src="/images/graduation.png"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <h1 class="headingservice">Authenticate to Abstract</h1>
      <p class="paragraphservice">Set up and configure SSO, SCIM, and Just-in-Time provisioning.</p>
      <a href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="services">
    <div class="image"><img src="/images/open.png"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <h1 class="headingservice">Abstract support</h1>
      <p class="paragraphservice">Get in touch with a human</p>
      <a href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this did the magic!
My objective was to have all the headings/columns aligned even when the viewport is resized instead of columns/blocks being squeezed and pushed up. Adding your code: 

.main,
.services {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

did the magic. Thank you once again, it would've never appeared to me to check these outside containers for alignment.